# Spotify script not printing songs / artists as expected

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, spotify

The code prints out the website title and url just fine

```
Status - Spotify
https://accounts.spotify.com/en/status
```

but it doesn't write out any of the song names or artists, despite my code otherwise

here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import bs4

login = open('login.txt','r')

user = login.readline()
password = login.readline()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver.get("https://accounts.spotify.com/en/status")

driver.find_element_by_id("login-btn-link").click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-facebook").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(user)
driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton").click()

print(driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)

driver.get("https://open.spotify.com/collection/tracks")

res = requests.get("https://open.spotify.com/collection/tracks")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

songs = soup.find_all("div", class_="ellipsis-one-line")
artists = soup.find_all("a", class_="tracklist-row__artist-name-link")

for div in songs:
    print(div.text)

for a in artists:
    print(a.text)

driver.quit
```

P.s. in order to use the log in via Facebook, you must write a login.txt formatted as following:

```
fakename@email.com
password
```

thanks for the help ahead of time :)

Comment: Are both `songs` and `artists` empty lists?

Comment: I took away the for loop and just said "print(songs)" and it did in fact return an empty list

Comment: Sounds like you need to rewrite this line: `songs = soup.find_all("div", class_="ellipsis-one-line")`

Comment: I figured I might be grabbing the wrong html tag, but I cannot think of what other tag the song title could possibly be. here is a screenshot for reference:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/526891145733603339/671430075039875072/unknown.png

Comment: Have you tried using `tracklist-name` instead of `ellipsis-one-line`?

Comment: yes I have used tracklist-name instead

Comment: Has it returned a non-empty list?

Comment: I printed it again but instead with tracklist-name and it does in fact return an empty list